# Error invoking stored procedure with input parameter from ADO.Net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ADO.Net. Here is my code and related error message. The error message says, @Param1 is not supplied, but actually it is supplied in my code. Any ideas what is wrong?

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Procedure or function 'Pr_Foo' expects
>   parameter '@Param1', which was not
>   supplied.

```
class Program
{
        private static SqlCommand _command;
        private static SqlConnection connection;

        private static readonly string _storedProcedureName = "Pr_Foo";
        private static readonly string connectionString = "server=.;integrated Security=sspi;initial catalog=FooDB";

        public static void Prepare()
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            _command = connection.CreateCommand();
            _command.CommandText = _storedProcedureName;
            _command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        }

        public static void Dispose()
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        public static void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlParameter Param1 = _command.Parameters.Add("@Param1", SqlDbType.Int, 300101);
                Param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter Param2 = _command.Parameters.Add("@Param2", SqlDbType.Int, 100);
                portal_SiteInfoID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                SqlParameter Param3 = _command.Parameters.Add("@Param3", SqlDbType.Int, 200);
                portal_RoleInfoID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

                _command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Prepare();

                Thread t1 = new Thread(Program.Run);
                t1.Start();
                t1.Join();

                Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\t" + ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance,

George

Comment: You seem to have sanitised your code for posting looking at the inconsistent parameter names. I suspect your sanitising of the code has hidden the actual problem. Can you double check what you have done?

Comment: What do you mean "check what you have done"? Appreciate if you could provide more details about what to check? :-)

Comment: you have ` SqlParameter Param2 = _command..... ` and then the next line reads ` portal_SiteInfoID.Direction = ....` - is that supposed to be the same parameter `Param2` ??

Comment: Plus: `ParameterDirection.Input;` is the default value - no need to keep specifying that over and over again, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace your function by below code and check :

```
public static void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param1", 300101);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param2", 100);
                _command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Param3", 200);

                _command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not add value to parameter. Signature of Add is Add(string parameterName, SqlDbType type, int size)... last parameter is size, not value. you can use method AddWithValue.

[**MSDN Article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=VS.100).aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(SYSTEM.DATA.SQLCLIENT.SQLPARAMETERCOLLECTION.ADD);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22);k(DevLang-CSHARP)&rd=true)

Answer (score 1):

Try taking the "@" symbol out of your .Add statements.  I never prepend the @ when adding parameters.

For example:

```
SqlParameter Param1 = _command.Parameters.Add("Param1", SqlDbType.Int, 300101);
```

Comment: I also tried to execute the store procedure from SSMS and provide the same parameters manually from GUI, it runs successfully.